# spring-data-jpa Avoid to delete Parent entity if there are child entities

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have a relationship Invoice -  InvoiceLine, and I want to avoid to delete an Invoice is there are InvoiceLines...
I would like to know which relationship is the best:

```
ALL ,
DETACH,
MERGE,
PERSIST,
REFRESH,
REMOVE
```

Comment: This depends on the relationship between Invoice and InvoiceLine and if the existence of one has any meaning without the other (from the names "Invoice" and "InvoiceLine" I assume that's not the case). Please add how you defined your relationships in your entities. You can also check this, it's well explained and covers all cascade types https://vladmihalcea.com/a-beginners-guide-to-jpa-and-hibernate-cascade-types/

Comment: you needn't any cascade for achieve this behavior. Until there are any invoice-line with foreign key invoice, you can't delete that invoice by default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It almost doesn't matter. 
As long as you don't use `REMOVE` and have an actual foreign key relationship between `Invoice` and `InvoiceLine`.

Without the `REMOVE` cascade deleting an `Invoice` won't touch the `InvoiceLines`. Which in turn will trigger the foreign key to prevent the operation.

Comment: But I want that an expection will be thrown if there are InvoiceLines

Comment: That's what will happen.